# Number of distinct right triangles formed by connecting vertices of a unit cube

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Suppose we have a unit cube in ${\mathbb{R}^3}.$
[image: Unit cube.]

We want to count the total number of distinct right triangles formed by connecting vertices of the unit cube. I can see that the total number of right triangles simply on a face of the cube will be $4$ and since there are $6$ faces we have $4 \times 6 = 24$ right triangles on the faces alone. Of course there are others across the cube's diagonals. I think the total will be $48$, due a symmetry across the diagonals, but am not entirely sure of my reasoning here, so I may be wrong.

If someone could elucidate or provide a better/more rigorous answer it would be appreciated.

Comment: The 24 triangles on the faces is correct. The challenging part is to know which triangles across the diagonals are actually right. Have you found examples of right triangles? And perhaps an example of a triangle that isn't a right triangle?

Comment: A different way to begin is to think about picking an edge (i.e. picking two vertices of the triangle) to start with. Then how many options are there for the third vertex? Multiply that by the number of edges, but divide by the number of times you possibly overcounted.

Comment: Using symmetry is a great idea. Another approach: how many right triangles does one vertex have s.t. the right angle is at that given vertex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key insight is that the only instance in which three vertices are selected that do **not** form a right triangle, is when those vertices form an equilateral triangle--i.e., no two vertices share an edge.

Since the cube circumscribes two distinct regular tetrahedra (cf. [stella octangula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stella_octangula)), there are a total of $8$ such triangles.  Since there are a total of $$\binom{8}{3} = 56$$ ways to choose any three distinct vertices, and each choice corresponds to a unique triangle, the number of right triangles is $56 - 8 = 48$.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in determining that there would be $48$ right triangles sharing at least one side with the cube. These can be counted as
$$\underbrace{4\times 6}_{\text{sharing 2 edges}} + \underbrace{2 \times 12}_{\text{sharing 1 edge}}=48$$

Observe that *these are all the triangles **any edge** makes with six remaining vertices*.

Now here is an argument that these are the only right triangles with vertices on the cube.

The distance between any two vertices of the cube belongs to the set $\{1,\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}\}$. This allows for right triangles only with sides $(1,1, \sqrt{2})$ and $(1,\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$. That is, one of the sides of the right triangle must be $1$, an edge of the cube. And we have counted all of these. $ \qquad \square$

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{8}{3}=56$ triangles in total, and the only non-right triangles are the equilateral triangles formed by the vertices exactly distance $1$ from a given vertex, and there are $8$ of these, so the answer is $56-8=48$.